# ListView Builder items are cut off when physics is set to NeverScrollableScrollPhysics

Tags: listview, flutter

I have a `GridView` builder which has a `ListView` inside it. The `gridView` has two `childs` 1. Header Text and 2.`ListView`
Header Text includes Under Graduate and `PostGraduate`.
`ListView` for Under Graduate includes 10 items while `ListView` for Post Graduate includes 3 items.

But i am able to see only 4 items in my  Under graduate `ListView` even though i have wrapped `ListView` inside an Expanded Widget.

I dont want to make the child listview scrollable. I have wrapped the inner ListView in Expandable but still it is not showing all items

Following is my code

```
return GridView.builder(
      gridDelegate:
          SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 2),
      shrinkWrap: true,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.black),
              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 4.0, 20.0, 4.0),
              margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8.0, 8.0, 8.0, 0.0),
              child: Text(
                "${disciplineModelDataList[index].disciplineName}",
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white, fontFamily: "suisseintlMedium"),
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
                child: ListView.separated(
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) =>
                        Divider(
                          height: 0.2,
                        ),
                    physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                    itemCount: disciplineModelDataList[index].years.length,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context3, int index3) {
                      return Card(
                        color: Colors.lightGreen,
                        margin: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0),
                          child: InkWell(
                            onTap: () {
                              print(index.toString());
                            },
                            child: Row(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Expanded(
                                  child: Text(
                                    "${disciplineModelDataList[index].years[index3].yearName}",
                                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        fontFamily: "okomitoBold",
                                        color: Colors.black),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Icon(Icons.arrow_forward)
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    }),
              ),
            )
          ],
        );
      },
      itemCount: disciplineModelDataList.length,
    );
```

Comment: `Grid` won't increase its size as per Child -  in Your Case `ListView`. Grid has `childAspectRatio` to vary Size.
`SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 2,childAspectRatio: 52.0)`

Comment: @anmol.majhail does not work. The GridView is not visible at all and it throws an error saying A RenderFlex overflowed by 31 pixels on the bottom.

Comment: That is what i am Saying - It wont' Work - `Grid` Wont Increase Size as per List view. Its Size is varied by `childAspectRatio`

Comment: @anmol.majhail so what should i try?

Answer (score 0):

You should not use a ListView inside GridView. Use Column instead

```
return GridView.builder(
  gridDelegate:
      SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 2),
  shrinkWrap: true,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.black),
          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 4.0, 20.0, 4.0),
          margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8.0, 8.0, 8.0, 0.0),
          child: Text(
            "${disciplineModelDataList[index].disciplineName}",
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white, fontFamily: "suisseintlMedium"),
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
          child: Column(
              children: List<Widget>.generate(disciplineModelDataList[index].years.length, (int index3) {
                return Card(
                  color: Colors.lightGreen,
                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0),
                    child: InkWell(
                      onTap: () {
                        print(index.toString());
                      },
                      child: Row(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Expanded(
                            child: Text(
                              "${disciplineModelDataList[index].years[index3].yearName}",
                              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontFamily: "okomitoBold",
                                  color: Colors.black),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Icon(Icons.arrow_forward)
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },),),
        )
      ],
    );
  },
  itemCount: disciplineModelDataList.length,
);
```

Comment: I need to use ListView as i am getting  dynamic data from the server and using the above method which you mentioned may cause a performance lag

Comment: @dshuketjr I tried what you mentioned and now i am getting bottom overflowed by 94 pixels